# How to pass object array as parameter in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, parameter-passing

The method is `public static void method(Object[] params)`, how should I call it in the following scenarios?

1. with one object as parameter `ClassA a`
2. with more than one objects as parameters `ClassA a`, `ClassB b`, `ClassC c`?
   thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can create the array of objects on the fly:

```
method(new Object[] { a, b, c});
```

Another suggestion is that you change the signature of the method so that it uses java varargs:

```
public static void method(Object... params)
```

Nice thing is that it is compiled into a method with the same signature as above `(Object[] params)`. But it may be called like `method(a)` or `method(a, b, c)`.

Comment: Beware, though, with the varargs variant, you'll have to explicitly cast to `Object` if you want to pas an `Object[]` as the only argument (and I don't think you'll get a warning if you forget).